# tsc cli - check if src files are newer than destination files

Tags: typescript, tsc

When using tsc with a tsconfig.json file, is there a check we can use to determine if the source files have been updated since the destination files have been written?

I want to run something like:

```
tsc --check && node .
```

that way I am ensuring that the latest transpilation has occurred. For small projects, I suppose just running `tsc` is enough, but for bigger projects that might take too long.

`tsc --check` would just make sure all the files made it to the target directory and have timestamps newer than the source files.

Comment: Do you actually transpile the files on production? If so, that seems like anti pattern. If not, you might consider using `ts-node` to serve from the sources and skip compiling.

Comment: no I am checking to see if they are transpiled correctly, w/o transpiling them :)